# Filter files by name with an Array

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am attempting to find all files in a folder that match any of the entries in an array so that I can move them to a different file for purpose of organization. I have PowerShell 2.0 at my disposal here; I am not sure if that is what's letting me down, I learned PowerShell 4.0 in school.

```cs
# Declared variables & array
$files = get-childitem "Y:\Downloads\"
$start = "Y:\Downloads\"
$end = "Y:\Downloads\sorted"
$fileEXT = "*.jokes.*","*.laughter.*","*.comedy.*","*.humour.*"

# Moving Files

#foreach ($file in $files) {
#  if ($file.Name -contains $fileEXT[0-9]) {
#    Move-Item $start $end
#  }
#}

foreach ($element in $fileEXT) {
  if ($files.Name -contains $element) {
    Move-Item $start $end
  }
}

#$start | Where-Object { $fileEXT -contains $_.Name } | Move-Item to $end
```

Comment: `-contains` is for collections. Use `-like`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [@BenH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169487/powershell-filter-files-by-name-with-an-array#comment71504227_42169487) mentioned, you're using the wrong operator. The [`-contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) operator allows you to check if an array contains a particular value (not part of a value):

```
'ab', 'cd', 'ef' -contains 'cd'    # returns true
'ab', 'cd', 'ef' -contains 'c'     # returns false
```

You probably confused the operator with the [`String.Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method, which allows you to check if a string contains a particular substring:

```
'abcdef'.Contains('cd')
```

Neither allows checking if a string contains any of a list of substrings, though. You need two loops for your approach, because you need to compare each file to each filter element, and you need the `-like` operator for wildcard comparisons. [Break](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break) from the inner loop so you don't try to move an item twice if it matches more than one filter element.

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
  foreach ($element in $fileEXT){
    if ($file.Name -like $element){
      Move-Item $file.FullName $end
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Comparing two arrays against each other with nested loops isn't going to perform well, though. A better approach would be to put just the search terms in your array and construct a [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) from it, so you can check for all filter elements in one go:

```
$words = 'jokes', 'laughter', 'comedy', 'humour'
$re    = '\.(' + ($words -join '|') + ')\.'

Get-ChildItem 'Y:\Downloads' |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -match $re } |
  Move-Item -Destination 'Y:\Downloads\sorted'
```

As a side note, while you could define the regular expression with a single string I wouldn't recommend doing that. Not unless you intend this to be a one-off script (and maybe not even then).

```
$re = '\.(jokes|laughter|comedy|humour)\.'   # don't do this
```

Making `$words` an array and joining the array to form the actual regular expression makes maintenance easier and allows you for instance to put the words in a separate file (separate data from code):

```
jokes
laughter
comedy
humour
```

and have your script read that file:

```
$words = Get-Content 'C:\wordlist.txt'
```

Comment: The latter method (array to regex) worked like a dream. Thank you so much! Very much appreciated! What a relief!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (dont forget remove -whatif)

Note:

```
- $_.Base contains file name without extension
- use !$_.PSIsContainer for take only files
```

Code :

```
$fileEXT = "test","laughter","comedy","humour"
$start = "Y:\Downloads\"
$end   = "Y:\Downloads\sorted"

#solution 1
Get-ChildItem $start | where {$Name=$_.BaseName; !$_.psiscontainer -and  ($fileEXT | where {$name -like "*$_*"}).Count -gt 0 } | 
move-item -Destination $end -WhatIf

#solution 1b (powershell 3)
Get-ChildItem $start -file | where {$Name=$_.BaseName; ($fileEXT | where {$name -like "*$_*"}).Count -gt 0 } |
move-item -Destination $end -WhatIf

#Solution 2 with regex
$fileEXT = "test|laughter|comedy|humour"
Get-ChildItem $start | where {!$_.psiscontainer -and  $_.BaseName -match $fileEXT} | 
move-item -Destination $end -WhatIf

#Solution 2b with regex (powershell 3), better solution gived by @TessellatingHeckler
$fileEXT = "test|laughter|comedy|humour"
Get-ChildItem $start -file | where { $_.BaseName -match $fileEXT} |
move-item -Destination $end -WhatIf
```

Comment: If I interpret the original `$fileEXT` correctly as wildcards the dots are meant literally. So it should be `$fileEXT = "\.test\.|\.laughter\.|\.comedy\.|\.humour\."` in the RegEx variants.

Comment: not sure, he use "contains" with string which contains "*"  , then how know what he want, i do a proposition :)

Comment: @LotPings Lot is right, I need the wildcard. So I'm searching for any file with *anything*.jokes.*anything*

Comment: @Esperento57 I appreciate your help, I will try it out tomorrow when I get a chance. Thank you so much!